# Mongo DB structure many to many relation for faster reads

Tags: mongodb, go, aws-lambda

I have to store an E-commerce product category relationship data (retrieved from external APIs) in mongo db. A category can contain many products, and a product can belong in many categories. There are 2 APIs available.

```
GET /categories
GET /categories/{id}/products
```

Both the APIs are pretty slow and can return only 10 items at once. Therefore, I decided to run a cron every 12 hours to store this data in mongo for faster read as my application is read intensive.

My application gets a request with a list of product ids and I have to return an array of categories against each product. Instead of calling the external API I am planning to read the data from mongo. How should I structure the data that is stored into mongo by the cron, so that I can retrieve it with a single query?

Note: I don't have an API where I can pass the product id and get the category ids associated with it.

Comment: It's not clear where to begin helping here. Is the data (and slowness) _currently_ in MongoDB? If not, have you tried troubleshooting the slowness with the existing approach prior to complicating the environment with this ETL process? What is "pretty slow" for your use case and how fast do you want it to be? Without knowing what the problem is or what the goals are its not clear that standing up an additional system would be beneficial. And schema design, even for a specialized usage, is usually a more involved conversation than can happen here on SO.

Comment: Updated. Hope it's clear now. A friend helped me out with this actually but keeping the post in case someone faces something similar.